# Improving the Django Query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am trying to optimize the following Django view.

```
def test_view(request, username):
  msgs = MyModel.objects.filter(name=username,
                                  created_at__range=[start_date, end_date]).order_by('-id')
  arr = []
  for msg in msgs:
    c = TestModel.objects.get(id=msg.test_id)
    if c not in arr:
        arr.append(c)

return render(request, "test.html", {'context': arr})
```

So I have two models.

- MyModel
- TestModel

### Goal:

- Fetch only unique values on a column called `test_id` from `MyModel` ordered by `id` of `MyModel`.
- Need only two parameters from `MyModel`. They are `test_id` and `created_at`

Currently I can see the following ways to improve.

- Use values in filter query to get only test_id and created_at.
- Use the mysql Distinct keyword in Django to uniquely search on test_id
- Unnecessary looping through the data queryset.
- Again searching for collection in arr seems really unnecessary and time consuming.

I am relatively new to Django. So any help on how I should proceed or any links I should read would be appreciated.

Comment: You should summarise what your view is doing. For example I can't understand why you set `c.user_name` and `c.last_time` within your loop, especially as you don't save anything.

Comment: What is `collection`? is it just `c` in your code?

Comment: Please show your models. Did you mean to write `TestModel.objects.get(test_id=msg.test_id)`? Mixing real and made-up variable names like `msgs` and `TestModel` makes your question confusing.

Comment: And which are the id/created_at values you need to get - those from MyModel or TestModel?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying your view as follows:

```
def test_view(request, username):
    msgs = MyModel.objects.filter(
        name=username, created_at__range=[start_date, end_date]
    ).order_by('-id').values_list('test_id', flat=True)

    arr = TestModel.objects.filter(id__in=msgs)

    return render(request, "test.html", {'context': arr})
```

That way you avoid just fetch all TestModel's you need in one query. Also, using values_list on MyModel query would allow to save memory since you don't use anything but test_id anyway.